# Optional Value passed from another View Controller becomes nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, ios10

I've checked all outlets are correctly connected and the value is passed from another view controller. But I cannot figure out what goes wrong...

[Screen Capture of the Debug Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKnRs.png)

Comment: Please show your code...It is hard to figure the issue without the related code. You do not need to show us the whole code but just the related parts to help us.

Comment: Here's where I try to pass the values from the first view controller:
http://imgur.com/0tNXUG1

And the way I use that value but turn out to get nil:
http://imgur.com/RvsnJWm

Comment: Are you sure when you are passing the `restaurant` it NOT nil? Have  you confirmed?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. But now I find out that the problem is just that I missed out the "override" for the prepare(for:sender:) method.

Thanks a lot!